# How to store note names and frequencies as data to use in other classes in java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to build some sort of array that will store the note names e.g. A4 and it's frequency e.g. 440
I also want to know what sort of class I should use to do this.

I want to be able to use a wave generator class to generate that note as a waveform like a Sine or square wave. Example

```
public SineGenerator(double amplitude, Note note, int bitRate, double duration) {
```

```
SineGenerator sg = new SineGenerator(0.8, C4(or middle C, 261.63Hz), 16, 1);
```

The Note class will index C4 in some sort of array and then return Middle C's frequency, 261.63 to the SineGenerator and SineGenerator will generate the sine wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are asking for a rough guide of how to implement the `Note` class.

The `Note` class will probably contain 3 main fields:

```
private char letter;
private int octave;
private boolean sharp;
```

A note such as D♭<sub>4</sub> will have a letter of `C`, `octave` of `4` and a `sharp` of `true`. As you can see, I am representing D♭ and C# as the same note here, as they have the same frequency, and the only thing of importance here seems to be the frequency.

`Note` will also have a `HashMap<String, Double>` or `HashMap<String, Integer>` to store the frequency of each note. Note that you don't need to store the semitones in this map, as you can just multiply the note below by 1.0595 (or `Math.pow(2, 1.0 / 12)`) to get the semitone frequency.

And then you'd write a method called `getFrequency`, which accesses the map. If `sharp` is true, multiply it by 1.0595 and return.

Here's a simple implementation that I have written:

```
class Note {
    private char letter;
    private int octave;
    private boolean sharp;

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> map;

    static {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("C0", 16);
        map.put("D0", 18);
        map.put("E0", 21);
        map.put("F0", 22);
        map.put("G0", 25);
        map.put("A1", 28);
        // ...
    }

    public Note(char letter, int octave, boolean sharp) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.octave = octave;
        this.sharp = sharp;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    public int getOctave() {
        return octave;
    }

    public boolean isSharp() {
        return sharp;
    }

    public double getFrequency() {
        String key = Character.toString(letter) + octave;
        double frequency = map.get(key);
        if (sharp) {
            frequency *= Math.pow(2, 1.0 / 12);
        }
        return frequency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For storing the note names and their respective frequency, look up HashMaps, it sounds like what you're looking for. 
Use the note names as Key and the frequencies as Value.

```
HashMap<String, Double> Notes = new HashMap<>();
```